# Trying to find a quick way to get windows path

Tags: python, windows

I'm new to python.
I know how to detect which os is installed but I'm trying to find a quick way to get the windows path rather then go a-z (c:\windows...x:\windows...).
Is there any quick way?

Edit:
Something like %systemroot% in windows (gives you full path).

Comment: Does `import os; os.getcwd()` give you what you want?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

```
import os
win_path = os.environ['WINDIR']
```

`WINDIR` is an environment variable set by windows that will point to `%SystemRoot%`

Comment: And that `%variable%` notation is how you read envirnonment variables in DOS command parser; turns out environment variables WINDIR and SYSTEMROOT hold the same value.

Comment: Correct. Just to be clear the variable will be evaluated by the `os.environ` call so it will return something like `C:\\Windows`, not a variable in the form `%SystemRoot%`.

Comment: `SystemRoot` is more reliable than `windir`, since many programs won't even run if it's not valid. It gets set by the session manager early in the boot process, whereas `windir` is contingent on a registry setting. It's better still to use the API for this: `import ctypes;` `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32');` `n = kernel32.GetWindowsDirectoryW(None, 0);` `buf = (ctypes.c_wchar * n)();` `kernel32.GetWindowsDirectoryW(buf, n);` `windir = buf.value`.